# Angular2 solution for validation of form with validation class or interface

Tags: angular, validation, angular2-forms

I need to have a validation class to use many times in separate section, suppose I have FormA that has a lot of elements, then I use the same form in multiple sections, so for validation i want to have a validation class for FormA then when i want to validate this form anywhere, i should have a validation class for this to avoid from different validation rules for the same form and have the unique rules for this form.
What i have searched and found is using a validation class for each element and then using that class, something like this:

```
import {FormControl} from '@angular/forms'; 
import {Directive,forwardRef} from '@angular/core'; 
import {NG_VALIDATORS} from '@angular/forms';
export function validateZip(c: FormControl) { 
  let ZIP_REGEXP:RegExp = new RegExp('[A-Za-z]{5}'); 

  return ZIP_REGEXP.test(c.value) ? null : { 
    validateZip: { 
      valid: false 
    } 
  }; 
} 

@Directive({ 
  selector: '[validateZip][ngModel],[validateZip][formControl]', 
  providers: [ 
   {
      provide: NG_VALIDATORS, useExisting: forwardRef(() =>  
      ZipValidator), multi: true
   } 
  ] 
}) 
export class ZipValidator { 

  validator: Function = validateZip; 

  validate(c: FormControl) { 
    return this.validator(c); 
  } 
}
```

and form to use this validation:

```
<form>
  <input type="text" name="zip" ngModel validateZip>
</form>
```

But what i need is to have a validation class that contain all validation rules of a form and use that.

Comment: Then make a shared service, where you put all the velaidations and inject it in the directive

Comment: @Vega could you write a sample?